# How to use sqrt on Double in Spark Scala

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-zeppelin

I am trying to calculate Root Mean Square Error (RMSE) manually on Spark (Scala 2.11)

[image: se]

As screenshot above, I calculate Square Error (SE) for each row

```
val predicted_with_sqr_err = predicted.withColumn("se", pow(($"medianHouseValue" - $"prediction"), lit(2)))
```

Then I calculate Mean Square Error (MSE)

```
val sum_se = predicted_with_sqr_err.agg(sum("se")).first.get(0)
val sum_se_double = sum_se.toString.toDouble
val mean_sqr_err = (1.0/predicted_with_sqr_err.count)*sum_se_double
```

It worked fine. But when I trying to square root to calculate Root Mean Square Error (RMSE).

```
val root_mean_sqr_err = sqrt(mean_sqr_err)
```

It give error:

```
<console>:83: error: overloaded method value sqrt with alternatives:
  (colName: String)org.apache.spark.sql.Column <and>
  (e: org.apache.spark.sql.Column)org.apache.spark.sql.Column
 cannot be applied to (Double)
       val root_mean_sqr_err = sqrt(mean_sqr_err)
```

[image: sqrt error]

How should I fix ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you are using `sqrt` function which is defined in `Spark SQL`. This function should be used only as a part of Spark SQL DSL (in selections, aggregations, etc.).
It takes `Column` or `String` as a parameter but you are trying to pass `Double`.
Instead use `sqrt` function which is defined in `scala.math` package:

```
val root_mean_sqr_err = math.sqrt(mean_sqr_err)
```